# Error when generating tf_record: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am attempting to use Tensorflow to create an object detection algorithm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5-SEZ_IvaM) tutorial. Basically, when I try to generate the tfrecord and put it in my data folder, I get an error. Details below. As a side note, I am using **Python 3.7.8**.

After using the Labelimg software to label my images, I have created three folders within my desktop directory entitled "data," "images," and "training. Within the images folder, there are two sub-folders called "test" and "train." After labeling my images in the PascalVOC format (.xml file outputs), I moved images into the "test" and "train" folders, respectively.

I first converted the xml files to csv files with the following code which was saved to my directory as xml_to_csv.py:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for directory in ['train','test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/{}'.format(directory))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv('data/{}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

Running the anaconda prompt command `python xml_to_csv.py` produces two CSV files in my "data" folder, with the training samples in the correct format.

Now, using the following code, I need to generate tf_record for both the train and the test files, using the following code. I have only one class, "weed," which has been edited below. The python file was saved as generate_tfrecord.py.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'weed':
        return 1
    else:
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

In the anaconda command prompt, running the command `python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv --output_path=data/test.record --image_dir=images/` produces the following error:

```
2020-10-15 11:20:43.224624: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-10-15 11:20:43.226712: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 22, in <module>
    flags = tf.app.flags
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

How can I solve this issue, so that I can create the tfrecord files to put directly in my "data" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tensorflow.app` is not available in latest tensorflow

try replacing

`flags = tf.app.flags` with `flags = tf.compat.v1.flags` (line number 14)

`writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)` with `writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)` (line number 77)

`tf.app.run()` with `tf.compat.v1.app.run()` (last line)

Comment: That did not do it. I got the same error. It appears the problem is in this line: ```if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()```

Comment: Yes, that is also a problem. replace `tf.app.run()` with `tf.compat.v1.app.run()`

Comment: Thank you, that helped!

Comment: Are these two lines not the exact same thing? "writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path) with writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path) (line number 77)"

Comment: sorry. replace with `writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)`